# difference between getline and fgets

Tags: c

Hello I'm currently working on a simple shell using C language
the problem is that i used the function `fgets` to read from stdin while it's forbidden in the exam I must use `getline`, so can change that without changing the whole code?

this is my code

```
void remove_end0fLine(char line[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while(line[i] != '\n')
        i++;
    line[i] = '\0';
}
  
void read_line(char line[])
{
    char* ret = fgets(line,MAX_CHAR,stdin);
    remove_end0fLine(line);
    
    if( strcmp(line,"exit")== 0 || ret == NULL)
        exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Not sure how to answer this question without just showing you exactly how to do it, which sort of defeats the educational value of the exam.  Yes, you can use getline as a replacement with minimal changes, but you'll need to modify the interface of `read_line`

Comment: Where's the question? It doesn't work?

Comment: Note that `getline` is allocating memory dynamically, which requires cleanup. But the fact that `fgets` is forbidden makes me think that there is something you did not understand, and replacing it with `getline` might be just a legal loophole